# Escrever uma informação no console do browser através do .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, navegador-de-internet, console, microsoft-azure

Preciso demonstrar informações no console no *browser* o clássico `console.log` do JavaScript, só que gostaria de fazer isto no *browser* com .Net e não no *output* do Visual Studio pois acredito que o Azure esteja impedindo a execução de alguns métodos de uma aplicação e como uma solução rápida pensei em inserir dentro dos métodos. Não sei se é possível, nem se é a melhor opção porem é uma resposta rápida.

Aplicação MVC4 , utilizo Firebug no *browser*.

Comment: De uma olhada na documentação de [solução de problemas](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/) em webapps. Tem como ativar vários logs, trackings. Inclusive tem como vc [debuggar remotamente](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2014/01/24/windows-azure-remote-debugging.aspx).

Comment: O que o @ThiagoLunardi disse pode ser uma boa mesmo. Mas uma solução porca poderia ser utilizando SignalR, ele vai te permitir mandar mensagens em tempo real para o cliente que poderão tratadas da maneira que você quiser através de JavaScript, aí com isso você as exibe no console.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível desta forma. O que roda no navegador é independente do que roda no servidor. Não tem como o servidor (no caso o ASP.NET) instruir diretamente o que o navegador deve executar.

O máximo que pode fazer é gerar uma página no C# (através de um *view* no MVC) que tenha um código em JavaScript  para ser executado pelo navegador (preferencialmente exista apenas a chamada ao JS nessa página e o código JS em si esteja em arquivo separado já definido e salvo de forma estática). Ou seja, o que importa para fazer isto é a parte que estará dentro do `<script></script>`.

Esta página obviamente será enviada ao servidor HTTP que posteriormente enviará ao navegador. O navegador que vai executar o código JS e fazer o que deseja.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Está errado o que eu disse?

Comment: Também não entendi o motivo do down vote.

Comment: Talvez a resposta seja fraquinha, mas não é motivo p/ negativar. Ainda mais se considerar que a pergunta não é algo que dê para responder muito diferente disto. Se tiver uma solução melhor que esta, basta a pessoa postar, eu vou positivar e aprender.

Comment: Exatamente, não existe uma resposta exata para essa pergunta.